# How to create a Mat from byte[] with JavaCV

Tags: javacv

Trying to use JavaCV for image processing to rotate image according to it's Exif data.
Reading and writing from file to either Mat or IplImage works, but since the file is being upload or downloaded, I also want to be able to do the same thing processing byte[] instead of having to write to file.

However, I cannot find how to create a Mat instance from byte[].
The method 'aMat.put(0, 0, byteArray)' which is mentions in some answers is not available on a Mat instance in javacp version 1.0 using javacpp-presets:opencv:3.0.0.

Trying to put the bytes in the Mat data via : 'aMat.data().put(imageBytes, 0, 0)' throws a NPE because data() returns null. I cannot find how to set the data since it is a JNI call.

Any idea's on how to create a opencv_core.Mat from byte[]?

Comment: How are you creating aMat?

Comment: with 'new opencv_core.Mat()'

Comment: In my code I do the following: `final opencv_core.Mat mYuv = new opencv_core.Mat(frameHeight + frameHeight / 2, frameWidth, opencv_core.CV_8UC1);` and then `mYuv.data().put(rawData);`. Maybe try setting the size before trying to get data?

Comment: It sounds like what you need is `imdecode(new Mat(imageByte), 0)`, but your question is unclear...

Answer (score 2):

Did you try using:

```
yourMat.data().put(yourByteArray);
```

Just make sure `yourMat` is of the right size.

Comment: Like I said, 'date()' returns null and I do not know how to make it non-null.

Comment: This also gave me a NullPointerException. Then `imdecode(new Mat(byteArray), 0)` worked for me